# how to import multiple javascript library to one object in angular 2+

Tags: angular, video, flowplayer, mpeg-dash

I have a working code for playing a video with flow player shown bellow
html:-

```
<figure id="expose" class="expose-wrap" >
  <div class="exposed"></div>
</figure>
```

ts:-

```
import * as flowplayer from './flowplayer';
export class DetailpageComponent implements OnInit {
  OnInit(){
  flowplayer('#expose>.exposed', {
            clip: {
              sources: [
               {
                 type: 'application/x-mpegurl',
                 src: url.m3u8
               }]
            }
          })
  }
}
```

the above code is for playing hls video and it is working fine. but I need to play dash video(.mpd file). I order to do that I need to add one more library which is flowplayer obect
in my packg

> ```
> "flowplayer": "^7.2.5",
> "flowplayer-dashjs": "github:flowplayer/flowplayer-mpegdash",
> ```

i have not able ti import flowplayer-dashjs libery in my component. 
Please help

Comment: have you install it via npm ?

Comment: yes I have installed it via npm